# Hook/event when a computed property with certain meta is defined in Ember in reopen/reopenClass?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ember.js

Is there a way to *know* when a property is defined on an `Ember.Object`'s prototype in Ember?

I was able to do this and get notified when and attribute is defined from `extend`:

```
App.Model = Ember.Object.extend()
App.Model.reopen Ember.MixinDelegate,
  willApplyProperty: (key) ->
  didApplyProperty: (key) ->
    # 'this' is the prototype

App.Person = App.Model.extend
  name: Ember.computed -> 'John'
```

But that's overkill, basically creating a callback for every property that gets defined on the prototype. In addition, that strategy doesn't work if you add attributes later using `reopen` (i.e. `didApplyProperty` never gets called for `email`):

```
App.Person = App.Model.extend
  name: Ember.computed -> 'John'    

App.Person.reopen
  email: Ember.computed -> 'example@gmail.com'
```

In this example, the goal is to be able to append these database columns to a class *cacheable* computed property, `App.Person.get('attributes')`.

```
App.Model.reopenClass
  emberFields: Ember.computed(->
    map = Ember.Map.create()

    @eachComputedProperty (name, meta) ->
      if meta.isAttribute
        map.set(name, meta)

    map
  ).cacheable()
```

Ember-data does this, but the problem is if you call `App.Person.get('attributes')` in between `extend` and `reopen`, then it gets cached after `extend`, so everything added later doesn't show up - it needs to invalidate the `App.Person.attributes` cache.

I tried doing that using `App.Person.propertyDidChange('attributes')`, but that doesn't seem to work. What I ended up having to do is override `reopen` and manually delete the cached value on the computed property:

```
App.Model.reopenClass
  reopen: ->
    result = @_super(arguments...)
    delete Ember.meta(@, 'attributes')['attributes']
    Ember.propertyDidChange(@, 'attributes')
    result
```

My question is, how do I invalidate (and clear the cached value of) a computed **class property** when a computed **instance property** (e.g. database column `email`) is defined using either `reopen` or `extend`?